# <noscript> is triggered for no reason in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, noscript

I think I found a bug in Chrome, and I kind of have no idea where to post but it may as well be a misconfiguration on my part or something.

Here is the issue. I'll include a screenshot which should explain the main idea of the issue.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

JavaScript is enabled and yet http://enable-javascript.com acts as if it weren't.

It's kind of vague though. Luckily Google Chrome's console makes everything clear.

> Blocked script execution in 'http://enable-javascript.com/' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

...but this is just Google Chrome's paranoia since there is no frame elements and "sandbox" is never mentioned in the code.

Any pointers would be helpful!

Update:

- Issue not present in incognito mode
- Disabled extensions did not help
- Reinstalling system did not help
- This affects all webkit browsers (Opera, Chrome, Chromium)

If I navigate to the URL directly, the issue is not present, however if I click a link to get to that page - the issue is in fact present. Refreshing on a dysfunctional page does not fix a thing.

Comment: Please  Confirm the  OS and  chrome versions as  the "current" stable / beta / unstable (canary )  have a different  layout  for that  part of the advanced settings..

Comment: Note that 'Sandboxing' is isolating executing code so that it cannot interact with other executing code. Sandboxing protects your system from malicious scripts, by keeping the script from doing things like reading files from your harddisk, reading/modifying memory from other processes or tabs. These days, Java, Javascript, and Flash generally run in a sandbox to protect users from drive-by-download trojans. IFrames are often dangerous, because they can dynamically inject foreign content into a page, so it makes sense to not allow their contents to execute arbitrary script code.

Comment: what are all those plugins you have installed in the top right corner?  are any of them blocking javascript?

Comment: @RussellUhl Well this is interesting. I went into incognito mode (no plugins) and it works fine. I will try to find the one causing the issue and update.

Comment: @RussellUhl Weird. I disabled all plugins, refreshed but the issue persists.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 Running current stable build on Linux Mint 17.1 64 bit

Comment: Not to be a pain but   mint has 2 versions on it at the moment  42.xx or 43.xx

Comment: I assume "All of them" includes adblock?  Make sure you disabled the plugins ENTIRELY, and not just "enabled for this page" or whatever.

Comment: oh.  also open developer tools and Ctrl+F5 to do a full refresh, and see if any errors open up in the console

Comment: @linuxdev2013 Aye? "Our latest release is Linux Mint 17.1, codename "Rebecca"." http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php

Comment: @RussellUhl Tried that, issue persists with same console output.

Comment: any similarity in youtube ?  (using @RussellUhl's   test)

Comment: @linuxdev2013 Strangely enough, youtube does not have this issue, at all.

Comment: With all plugins enabled?

Comment: @linuxdev2013 Exactly. I think this eliminates the possibility that plugins are causing it.

Comment: can you provide output from '(dmesg |grep 'error|fatal|warning' ; apt policy google-chrome-\* ; sudo grep -i 'error|fatal|warning' /var/log/{syslog,messages} ) |pastebin  please

Comment: @linuxdev2013 I think I ran it right.. http://paste.linuxmint.com/view/qokz/

Comment: Make sure your ISP or proxy does not add frames to web pages you visit. Open developer tools, go to the `Elements`/`Sources` tab to view the source, search for the word `frame`.

Comment: @aff Did that already. "frame" is not mentioned anywhere in the code.

Comment: Try this:  Save [this](http://pastebin.com/MUFsyEVK) as a basic html file on your computer and open it.  Let me know what it says.  This is about as basic of a Javascript check as you can get.  The page you've been using has jQuery, Lightbox, and Google Analytics involved which could be causing issues.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can use this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --allow-scripts
```

Comment: OP is using Linux Mint not a Windows

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Correct but I only found this thread when searching for this error. I hope my answer will help other Windows users like myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try running chrome from terminal:

`./chrome.exe --args --allow-scripts`

Comment: This Q is from an installation I no longer have but how in the world is this Windows? It's linux...

Comment: It looked like windows, my apologies. I've changed it to Linux.

Comment: Now I see it. It's Linux Mint.